# How do I see what props have changed in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am looking to make some performance improvements to my React components.

If I have a component that is called like:

```
    <MyComponent
        anObject={someObject}
        aFn={someFn}
        aValue={value}
    />
```

React will only "re-render" that component if `anObject`, `aFn`, or `aValue` has changed. **If I know my function is re-rendering, how can I tell which of those three props caused it?**

I know I can `console.log` `aValue` and see if it changes, but what about the object and the function. They can have the same values but be referencing different memory. Can I output the memory location?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a `useEffect` hook for each prop:

```js
const MyComponent = ({ anObject, aFn, aValue }) => {
    React.useEffect(() => {
        console.log('anObject changed');
    }, [anObject]);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        console.log('aFn changed');
    }, [aFn]);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        console.log('aValue changed');
    }, [aValue]);

    // Your existing component code...
};
```

When the component mounts all three effects will run, but after that the logs will reveal what specifically is changing.

Comment: That's clever. I'll try it out!

Comment: While this is correct, it is onerous to check every prop individually. I'd recommend building a utility hook to check all props at once, as it can save a lot of time when debugging render loops issues and optimizing pages.

Comment: Thanks @RowanBaker-French for crafting a generic utility to do this in your answer. It's also worth noting that the official [React Developer Tools](https://react.dev/learn/react-developer-tools) has a profiler that can track why each component rerenders, including which props changed. The profiler exposes much more info that is helpful for optimizing a full app or entire screen, and it doesn't require writing any special code that must be deleted later. I'd highly recommend using the profiler for more comprehensive debugging/optimization.

Answer (score 5):

To add to the existing answer, I created a simple utility hook for this purpose.

```js
function useWhatChanged(props: { [prop: string]: unknown }) {
  // cache the last set of props
  const prev = React.useRef(props);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // check each prop to see if it has changed
    const changed = Object.entries(props).reduce((a, [key, prop]: [string, unknown]) => {
      if (prev.current[key] === prop) return a;
      return {
        ...a,
        [key]: {
          prev: prev.current[key],
          next: prop,
        },
      };
    }, {} as { [k: string]: any });

    if (Object.keys(changed).length > 0) {
      console.group('Props That Changed');
      console.log(changed);
      console.groupEnd();
    }

    prev.current = props;
  }, [props]);
}

function MyComponent(props: Props) {
  // Pass an object of variables you want to check for changes
  useWhatChanged(props)
}
```

Then just check the console to see which of the props have changed as well as their previous and current values.